# jQUery fadeIn based on url?

Tags: jquery, url, fadein

let say i pass url, example.php?mode=select&ID=1#age

is it possible to add jquery fadeIn based on url?

this url will be on another page, when user click it, a page will load and hence the age filed should be fade in.

if this not possible, is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the if there's a [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) set on `document.ready` and if so, call [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) on that element, like this:

```
$(function() {
  if(location.hash) $(location.hash).fadeIn();
});
```

So for example if your URL was `....#age`, this would fade in the `id="age"` element.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similiar with a URL like this:

http://site.com/page/view/#219

```
var theHash = window.location.hash;
theHash=theHash.substr(1);

$("#f"+theHash).css('backgroundColor',"#E47527");
$("#f"+theHash).animate({backgroundColor: "#ffefe3" }, 2000);
```

probably more efficient ways, however. used on links with an ID like "#f111"